# Getting Array Data in php

Tags: php, arrays, function

I need to be able to get the data out of the following functions:
    `getStuff();`
    `getRelateStuff();`
    `getRelatedStuffInStuff();`

Begin Code:

```
function getStuff()
{
   return array("It", "Works");
}

function Stuff()
{
   $value = array(getStuff());
   foreach ($value as $key => $value) 
   {
      echo "$key  $value <br />\n";
   }

}

function getRelatedStuff()
{
   return array("hello" => "world", "cake"=> "is a lie");
}

function RelatedStuff()
{

   $value = array(getRelatedStuff());
   foreach ($value as $key => $value) 
   {
      echo "$key  $value <br />\n";
   }

}

//Related in Stuff
function getRelatedStuffInStuff()
{
   $s1 = array("hello" => "world", "cake"=> "is a lie");
   $s2 = array("apple" => "mac", "microsoft"=> "windows", "linus" => "linux");
   $s3 = array("OSX" => "10.6", "Ubuntu" => "11.04", "Windows" => "7");
   return array($s1, $s2, $s3);
}

function RelatedInStuff()
{

   $value = array(getRelatedStuffInStuff());
   foreach ($value as $key => $value) 
   {
      echo "$key  $value <br />\n";
   }

}

?>
```

When I try to view this page in a web browser it just shows a blank page. I am doing anything correctly? What should or what can I change?

Comment: the piece of code you posted (I think it's the second time I see it) just has functions definitions. You need to call those functions (and actually generate HTML somewhere if you want it to be pretty).

Comment: where is your `getStuff()` method? and where are your function calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this at the end of your code (the `?>` is the last line in what you posted):

```
?>
<html><body>
<?php
RelatedInStuff();
?>    
</body></html>
```

This will actually generate some HTML and *call* one of your functions.

Comment: well there you go, you've started to see some output. Now you need to rework your code. Start with trying to display, just _one_ array with _one_ function call. Once you've got that working as you want, add the other functions in one at a time.

Comment: @Mat I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Thoughts? I added the HTML and as previously stated I get the "O Array" output.

Comment: You need to learn more about PHP arrays. Try with _much_ simpler things than what you posted.

Comment: @Mat for some reason I have always struggled with Array. I don't exactly know why, just have though.

Comment: you're trying to do too much at a time. Practice with a single array and try to print only that contents. You don't actually need a function for this. Once you have that working, try with two, make a function. Don't add anything more until you've actually understood what you did in the previous step.

Comment: @Phill The reason you get 0 Array is because the results of getRelatedStuffInStuff() is an array. In RelatedInStuff() you have put the results inside an other array. 

When you do the foreach loop you are looping over the array created by `$value = array(getRelatedStuffInStuff());` 0 is the $key and Array is the $value (the results of getRelatedStuffInStuff()) 'Array' is what happens when you try to echo an array.

To help you debug you can print out the array: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($value); echo '</pre>';`

Answer (score 4):

If this is your full code... you have to call the functions.

Also your functions already return an array so you don't need to wrap those calls in array(...).